# RSPEC undefined method 'jobs' for nil:NilClass (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

Im testing my controller with RSPEC

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_customer



  def jobs
    @jobs = @customer.jobs
  end



private 

  def set_customer
    if params[:id]
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    else
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
    end
  end
```

My Rspec test looks like so:

**TEST CODE**

```
describe "GET job" do 
  it "renders the job view" do
     customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
     controller.stub(:set_customer).and_return(customer)
     get (:jobs)
     expect(response).to render_template("customers/jobs.json.jbuilder")
  end
end
```

The error I am getting - it happens during the call to get(:jobs) is:

**ERROR:**

```
Failures:

  1) CustomersController assigns @jobs
     Failure/Error: get (:jobs)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass
        # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:37:in `jobs'
```

I have another test, but that one also gives me the same error when the call to get(:jobs) is made. 
I am subbing out the set_customer function, and returning a customer variable (made via factory girl). I am not sure why it is still undefined? For reference (again) the error is occurring for this method in the controller:

```
def jobs
  @jobs = @customer.jobs
end
```

If this isn't the correct way to do this, how can i generate a @customer variable like its done in the controller set_customers function(via params) and pass it to the rspec test?

Comment: Check out `binding.pry`. Drop one in `set_customer` to see if it gets executed, another one in `jobs` to investigate objects and params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stubbing `set_customer` doesn't set the instance variable, I think you don't even need to stub, you already have the actual customer

```
describe "GET job" do 
  it "renders the job view" do
     customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
     get(:jobs, id: customer)
     expect(response).to render_template("customers/jobs.json.jbuilder")
  end
end
```

Comment: @SUPERUSER it should work with the brackets, the only issue is that i put a space before the brackets, i'll fix that

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an `:id` or `:customer_id` param value to the request call, e.g.:

```
get :jobs, id: 42
```